# urlencode not work

Tags: python, urllib2

code:

```
import urllib,urllib2
url = 'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php'
print urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print urllib2.urlopen(url,urllib.urlencode({'nothing':12345})).read()
```

the question I encounter is why the two 'print' output the same content,
where is problem in my code?

Comment: Well, obviously the website you are contacting is ignoring the string `nothing=12345` you send in the POST request.  Seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: I just like that pythonchallenge is written in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to urlopen is data to be POSTed. If you want URL arguments you need to create the URL:

```
print urllib2.urlopen("%s?%s" % (url,urllib.urlencode({'nothing':12345}))).read()
```

Comment: but in the python online mannul,the urlopen function can accpet an optional second parameter which respresent 'data'

Comment: eh..sorry.url arguments isn't same with POSTed data?

Comment: If you are supposed to access the resource using the POST method, then the data argument is what you want. If you're supposed to "GET" with URL Query parameters then you need to do as I've suggested

Comment: oh,i just forgot the distinction between POST and GET ,thks